# Space cannot be used in vertical string with unicode character

Tags: front-end, string-manipulation, boxes, unicode

To reproduce the issue, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create 3 placeholders and enter `你`   `好` (or `α`   `β`) in sequence and wrap it with a pair of `"` and execute. The output will be a pink box with the following message:

> A `GridBox` containing rows of differing lengths was encountered.

[image]

```
$Version
(* "13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)
```

Comment: Can you please include the copy-paste code with the vertical space? I don't know how to type it in ... :)

Comment: @Domen That code can't be pasted here normally. But you can type it by **Ctrl** key and **Enter** key at the same time.

Comment: Hm, I have [no problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQGSQ.png). Please select cell `In[22]`, then go to the menu `Cell > Show Expression` and include this in your question. This might help us deducing what is wrong with your input.

Comment: @Domen   This one: `Cell[BoxData["\"\<\!\(\*GridBox[{{\:4f60},{ },{\:597d}
}]\)\>\""], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.904009235716051*^9, 3.9040092474645653`*^9}, {3.904009376788827*^9, 3.9040093797224426`*^9}},
 CellLabel->"In[22]:="]`

Comment: I see it now. I get [the same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxOHq.png) if I want to leave an empty space in between; `GridBox` somehow doesn't allow it. I don't know what to do, but I know some people here speak Chinese so they probably know how to deal with this :)

Comment: @Domen In your case, English also will cause this problem. It is a little weird.

Comment: Does it make sense to use a GridBox inside of a string? I think GridBox will expect a complete, rectangular grid of data, so if a "cell" is missing, it can't properly display, and since it's inside a string, I'm not really sure why we should expect anything readable to result.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem in latest version, which version are you in?

Comment: @xzczd 13.3.1. What version are you using?

Comment: Can you add the output of `$Version` to your question?

Comment: @xzczd Of course. I have done as you suggested.

Comment: OK, I manage to reproduce the issue, so you have used Ctrl+Enter to create 3 placeholder and enter ”你 好“ in sequence. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug to me. For Chinese users, the easiest work around is probably, using the  fullwidth space (全角空格) 　 (`FromCharacterCode[12288]`) instead of the halfwidth space  .

[image]

Comment: May you tell me how did you know this and what input method did you use?

Comment: @Y.zeng I find this just by guess. (The message complains about "rows of differing lengths" , so I guess a fullwidth space may help. ) I'm using 小小输入法 (with 郑码 as the input method), but any Chinese IME should have the button for fullwidth/halfwidth switch.

Comment: You can use the Chinese input method default in Windows 11, which will be more clean. However, even if the length of them are different, Mathematica should have ability to deal with it, not output error. So, it should be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use simply

```
  "你\n \n 好"
```

[image: chinese vertical]

Of course exist a text formatting option for classical chinese print right to left, vertical, I suppose.

Comment: But it is different from **Ctrl** + **Enter**.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems with it:

```
"\!\(\*GridBox[{{\:4f60},{\:597d}\n }]\)"
```

[image]

I was able to insert blank in between by this code:

```
"\!\(\*GridBox[{{\:4f60},{"<>FromCharacterCode[10240]<>"},{\:597d}\n }]\)"
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you did not use **Ctrl** + **Enter**. If you used them, you didn't add a space in the middle.

Comment: What character code has your vertical space?

Comment: A **space**, just press **space** key to achive it.

Comment: Why you call it then a vertical space when it is an ordinary space?

Comment: Sometimes there are three character, sometimes there are two. I just want to keep them align top and bottom together.

Comment: Does the new code I updated work for you?

Comment: Yes. The second way works. Thanks.